# Summing up CSV power plant data by technology and plant name

Tags: python, excel, csv, openoffice-calc

I've got a question regarding the [Form 860 data](https://www.eia.gov/electricity/data/eia860/) about US power plants.

It is organized block-wise and not plant-wise. To become useful, the capacity numbers must be summed up.

How may I get the total capacity for each technology for each plant (by name or id)?

```
Plant ID,Plant Name,Nameplate Capacity (MW),Technology,...
3,Barry,153.1,Natural Gas Steam Turbine,..
3,Barry,153.1,Natural Gas Steam Turbine,..
3,Barry,403.7,Conventional Steam Coal,..
3,Barry,788.8,Conventional Steam Coal,..
3,Barry,195.2,Natural Gas Fired Combined Cycle,..
3,Barry,195.2,Natural Gas Fired Combined Cycle,..
10,Greene County,299.2,Natural Gas Steam Turbine,..
10,Greene County,269.2,Natural Gas Steam Turbine,..
10,Greene County,80,Natural Gas Fired Combustion Turbine,..
10,Greene County,80,Natural Gas Fired Combustion Turbine,..
10,Greene County,80,Natural Gas Fired Combustion Turbine,..
```

Only summing up is easily doable with `SUMIF` in Calc or Excel, but how to filter by technology?
So I've better wanted to do this by pure CSV processing.

Is this possible with e.g. Python? Thanks for any good answer!

Comment: In Excel you can do this pretty simply with a Pivot Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Python, you can use the 3rd party Pandas library:

**Read your Excel file into a dataframe**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('file_in.xlsx')
```

**Calculate GroupBy with sum**

Grouper key(s) may either be a scalar or a list. For example, these are both valid:

```
res = df.groupby('Technology')['Capacity'].sum().reset_index()
res = df.groupby(['ID', 'Name'])['Capacity'].sum().reset_index()
```

We use `reset_index` to return a dataframe.

**Export back to Excel**

```
res.to_excel('file_out.xlsx')
```

Comment: I would like to have the entries in the "Technology" column as column headers. Like this?

 `Name,Capacity,Conventional Steam Coal,Natural Gas Fired Combined Cycle,Natural Gas Steam Turbine`
 `Barry,2569.5,1192.5,1070.8,306.2`

Is this doable?

Comment: Yes, but this would be [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634368/create-pandas-pivot-table

Answer (score 0):

Pandas library will be a useful library. It is used to process data frames.

Importing Pandas Library

`import pandas as pd`

Reading the form csv file

`df = pd.read_csv("form.csv")`

Finding the sum

`df.groupby('PlantName')['NameplateCapacity'].sum()`