# Pandas group-by / pivot data while entries of one column become new lables

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to sum-up the capacities of power plants by technology with python + pandas ([previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623539/summing-up-csv-power-plant-data-by-technology-and-plant-name)).

For this task the data must be grouped / pivoted while the column entries in column "Technology" should become column labels

This is my input:

```
Plant Name,Nameplate Capacity,Technology,...
Barry,153.1,Natural Gas Steam Turbine,..
Barry,153.1,Natural Gas Steam Turbine,..
Barry,403.7,Conventional Steam Coal,..
Barry,788.8,Conventional Steam Coal,..
Barry,195.2,Natural Gas Fired Combined Cycle,..
Barry,195.2,Natural Gas Fired Combined Cycle,..
```

And the desired output:

```
Plant Name,Natural Gas Steam Turbine,Conventional Steam Coal,Natural Gas Fired Combined Cycle,..
Barry,306.2,1192.5,390.4,..
```

I've tried a few commands, but nothing worked out:

```
df.groupby(['Plant Name', 'Technology']).sum().pivot('Plant Name', 'Technology').fillna(0)
```

or

```
#with numpy as np
res = df.pivot_table(index=["Plant Name"], columns=["Plant Name"], values=["Technology"], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

### An additional question

How can I find out the largest entry (e.g. "Conventional Steam Coal" in my example) for each row as a new column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need change columns names and add parameter `fill_value`:

```
res = df.pivot_table(index="Plant Name", 
                     columns="Technology", 
                     values="Nameplate Capacity", 
                     aggfunc=np.sum,
                     fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (res)
Technology Plant Name  Conventional Steam Coal  \
0               Barry                   1192.5   

Technology  Natural Gas Fired Combined Cycle  Natural Gas Steam Turbine  
0                                      390.4                      306.2
```

First solution should be changed with specify column for aggreate `sum` and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape:

```
res = (df.groupby(['Plant Name', 'Technology'])['Nameplate Capacity']
         .sum()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .reset_index())
print (res)
Technology Plant Name  Conventional Steam Coal  \
0               Barry                   1192.5   

Technology  Natural Gas Fired Combined Cycle  Natural Gas Steam Turbine  
0                                      390.4                      306.2
```

Comment: How can I use multiple "index" columns, which are all same for all blocks? In addition to Plant Name I would like to Plant ID, State, etc.

Comment: @LuisPaganini - Then change `index="Plant Name"` to `index=["Plant Name", "State"]`

Comment: Even if it's against the rules: May you please also answer my second question (that I don't have to open a new one)?

Comment: @LuisPaganini - I think it is simple, need `df['top'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)`, but first remove `.reset_index()`

Comment: Sorry for not getting it: How would the actual code line look like? _reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype_

Comment: @LuisPaganini - It means some column are not `numeric`, do you remove `.reset_index()` like `df.pivot_table(index="Plant Name", 
                     columns="Technology", 
                     values="Nameplate Capacity", 
                     aggfunc=np.sum,
                     fill_value=0)` ?

Comment: @jezrael Im faced with a similar problem, could you  answer it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64330740/how-to-filter-dataframe-based-on-condition-and-use-it-to-create-pivot-tables-in)

Answer (score 0):

You have misaligned parameters to `pd.pivot_table`. Columns represent category labels, while values represent the data which is to be aggregated.

In addition, you should use `'sum'` instead of `np.sum`, since Pandas is optimized to use appropriate alogrithms given a string input:

```
res = df.pivot_table(index='Plant Name', columns='Technology',
                     values='Nameplate Capacity', aggfunc='sum')

print(res)

Technology  Conventional Steam Coal  Natural Gas Fired Combined Cycle  \
Plant Name                                                              
Barry                        1192.5                             390.4   

Technology  Natural Gas Steam Turbine  
Plant Name                             
Barry                           306.2
```