# How to group by column in a dataframe and create pivot tables in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot, export-to-excel

I have the following table `df` .

```
ID  CATEG   LEVEL   COLS    VALUE   COMMENT
1    A       3      Apple    388    comment1
1    A       3      Orange   204    comment1
1    A       2      Orange   322    comment1
1    A       1      Orange   716    comment1
1    A       1      Apple    282    comment1
1    A       2      Apple    555    comment1
1    A              Berry    289    comment1
2    A              Car      316    comment1
1    B              Berry    297    comment1
1    B       3      Apple    756    comment1
1    B       2      Apple    460    comment1
1    B       3      Orange   497    comment1
1    B       2      Orange   831    comment1
1    B       1      Orange   225    comment1
1    B       1      Apple    395    comment1
2    B              Car      486    comment1
1    C       2      Orange   320    comment1
1    C       1      Orange   208    comment1
1    C       1      Apple    464    comment1
1    C       2      Apple    613    comment1
1    C       3      Apple    369    comment1
1    C              Berry    474    comment1
2    C              Car      888    comment1
1    C       3      Orange   345    comment1
2    B              Car      664    comment2
```

I want to create this view in `dataframe` and write in excel for each group of  `ID`.Example for `ID` `1`. In my sample there is only one comment so sheet name be like `ID_COMMENT` like  `1_comment1`:-

```
  Berry     Apple     Orange        
         1   2   3  1   2   3
A   289 388 555 282 204 322 716
B   297 756 460 395 497 831 225
C   474 369 613 464 345 320 208
```

If `LEVEL` is `None/na` I should be able to create/ split the `df` based on `COLS` and `comments` alone with name  "ID_NULL_COMMENT" as sheet name like:-
`2_NULL_comment1` sheet :-

```
   CATEG    Car
     A      316
     B      486
     C      888
```

`2_NULL_comment2` sheet :-

```
CATEG   Car
 B      664
```

what I tried :

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
writer = ExcelWriter('Values.xlsx')
distinct_id_df= np.unique(df[['ID']], axis=0)   
for ID in  distinct_id_df.iloc[:,0] :
    sample_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for df in sample_df:
        for i in(distinct_id_df):
            distinct_id_df = df.groupby['ID'].pivot_table('VALUE', ['LEVEL','CATEEG'],'COLS')
        sample_df = sample_df.append(df)
        print(sample_df.shape, '===>', datetime.now())
    sample_df.to_excel(writer,'{}''{}'.format(id).format(comments),index= False)

writer.save()
```

This is not correct clearly, Im unable to do the `pivot` correctly and also stuck on how to  loop correctly to place in different sheet.

Comment: Sheetname `ID_NULL_COMMENT` for.. `LEVEL` = `na` within each group of `ID` and if `LEVEL`=`na` for the whole `ID` group  sheetname `ID_COMMENT`

Comment: So the same `ID` can have sheetnames `ID_NULL_COMMENT`, `ID_COMMENT` for one `COMMENT`. If `ID` does not have `na`/`None` then sheetname will only be `ID_COMMENT` for one `COMMENT`

Comment: YEs correct, for now Im not using `COMMENT` so it will be `1`

Comment: No in the sample data unfortunately there is no `None` for `ID` `1` , so it will just be `1_comment1`, `2_comment1` and `2_comment2`

Comment: @jezrael Have added the data you asked for .Have already worked on these lines as you know, would be glad if you could help to update logic in the code where if ` LEVEL` is `na` within `ID` how to append with the initial pivot `df` or how to loop using `lambda`

Comment: it looks good, for first check, working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2], 'CATEG': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B'], 'LEVEL': [3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0,  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0,  np.nan, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,  np.nan,  np.nan, 3.0,  np.nan], 'COLS': ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Berry', 'Car', 'Berry', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Car', 'Orange', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Berry', 'Car', 'Orange', 'Car'], 'VALUE': [388, 204, 322, 716, 282, 555, 289, 316, 297, 756, 460, 497, 831, 225, 395, 486, 320, 208, 464, 613, 369, 474, 888, 345, 664], 'COMMENT': ['comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment1', 'comment2']})
```

---

```
#check misisng values
mask = df['LEVEL'].isna()

#split DataFrames for different processing
df1 = df[~mask]
df2 = df[mask]

#pivoting with differnet columns parameters
df1 = df1.pivot_table(index=['ID','COMMENT','CATEG'], 
                      columns=['COLS','LEVEL'],
                      values='VALUE')
# print (df1)

df2 = df2.pivot_table(index=['ID','COMMENT','CATEG'], columns='COLS',values='VALUE')
# print (df1)

from pandas import ExcelWriter
with pd.ExcelWriter('Values.xlsx') as writer: 
    
    #groupby by first 2 levels ID, COMMENT
    for (ids,comments), sample_df in df1.groupby(['ID','COMMENT']):
        #removed first 2 levels, also removed only NaNs columns
        df = sample_df.reset_index(level=[1], drop=True).dropna(how='all', axis=1)
        #new sheetnames by f-strings
        name = f'{ids}_{comments}'
        #write to file
        df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=name)
        
    for (ids,comments), sample_df in df2.groupby(['ID','COMMENT']):
        df = sample_df.reset_index(level=[1], drop=True).dropna(how='all', axis=1)
        name = f'{ids}_NULL_{comments}'
        df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=name)
```

Another solution without repeating code:

```
mask = df['LEVEL'].isna()

dfs = {'no_null': df[~mask], 'null': df[mask]}

from pandas import ExcelWriter
with pd.ExcelWriter('Values.xlsx') as writer: 
    
    for k, v in dfs.items():
        if k == 'no_null':
            add = ''
            cols = ['COLS','LEVEL']
        else:
             add = 'NULL_'
             cols = 'COLS'
        
        df = v.pivot_table(index=['ID','COMMENT','CATEG'], columns=cols, values='VALUE')
          
        for (ids,comments), sample_df in df.groupby(['ID','COMMENT']):
            df = sample_df.reset_index(level=[1], drop=True).dropna(how='all', axis=1)
            name = f'{ids}_{add}{comments}'
            df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=name)
```

Comment: The `LEVELS` are not displayed  in excel . Those columns having `LEVELS` not `na` should display level name (1,2,3)

Comment: @Scope - For me working correct, in first sheet in second row

Comment: `LEVEL 1 2 3 1 2 3
`

Comment: @Scope - I got this [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mybvrhdw0prr4lu/Values.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Which part of code does that? for me in none of the sheet it is shown. Also if an `ID` has whole `LEVEL` column `na` then `sheetname` should be just `ID_COMMENT`,If an ID has both `na` and number(1,2,3) for `LEVEL`, then the `COLS` for `na` is to be split in another sheet (or append in same sheet as first column), as `ID_NULL_COMMENT` whereas the other sheet with same `ID` will be `ID_COMMENT`

Comment: Im trying only the second one , shouldnt it be `columns= 'cols'` or `columns=['cols']`

Comment: @Scope  - EDITED answer with input data, for you not working?

Comment: My level values are `strings` ran on my data and it didnt work .. Im just looking into it why

Comment: @Scope - hmm, so working with sample data, but not with real data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223086/discussion-between-scope-and-jezrael).