# How to drop null values in dataframe after groupby while writing to excel

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot, export-to-excel

I have the following `dfe`:-

```
  ID CATEG   LEVEL     COLS    VALUE COMMENTS
    1   A        2     Apple    428  comment1
    1   A        3     Apple    175  comment1
    1   C        1     Apple    226  comment1
    1   C        2     Apple    884  comment1
    1   C        3     Apple    289  comment1
    1   B        1     Apple    712  comment1
    1   B        2     Apple    849  comment1
    2   B        3     Apple    376  comment1
    2   C        None  Orange   591  comment1
    2   B        None  Orange   135  comment1
    2   D        None  Orange   423  comment1
    2   A        None  Orange   866  comment1
    2            None  Orange   496  comment2
```

I want to `pivot` by one column `COLS` of  `dfe` , groupby `ID` and write in excel such that each `ID` data is on one sheet.
What I tried :-

```
df=pd.pivot_table(dfe,index=['ID','CATEG','LEVEL'],columns=['COLS'],values=['VALUE'])
    

with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx',options={'nan_inf_to_errors': True}) as writer :
        df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=str(x.name),na_rep=0,index=True))
writer.save()
```

The problem I'm facing doing so is after the `groupby` many columns are 0, I want to remove columns which are null after the `groupby` and before writing to excel. I cannot remove null column before `groupby` as the whole column won't be null then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all columns with only missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) by `how='all'` and `axis=1` parameters:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx',options={'nan_inf_to_errors': True}) as writer :
        df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.dropna(how='all', axis=1).to_excel(writer,sheet_name=str(x.name),na_rep=0,index=True))
writer.save()
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply, this worked, but I'm unable to get all the headers on one line, how do I do that eg :  `0 value` is shown on first row then  pivot column headers in second row and `ID`, `CATEG` ,  `LEVEL` in next row,, I want all the headers in one row how do I do this. `header=false` removes all the 3 rows

Comment: try change `df=pd.pivot_table(dfe,index=['ID','CATEG','LEVEL'],columns=['COLS'],values=['VALUE'])` to `df=pd.pivot_table(dfe,index=['ID','CATEG','LEVEL'],columns='COLS',values='VALUE')`

Comment: It worked . Im facing an issue where all numbers appearing in scinetifc format `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format` this makes the numbers as decimals , which im trying to avoid, is there any other way to avoid scientific fromatting this

Comment: @Scope - Some ideas - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737300/suppressing-scientific-notation-in-pandas).

Comment: All these converts to float which im trying to avoid, as i dont have any float values in my data..

Comment: @Scope - Unfortunately not idea :(  It seems data related issue, so for test is necessary create data with same issue.

Comment: thanks no issues. Also could you answer my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64330740/how-to-group-by-column-in-a-dataframe-and-create-pivot-tables-in-a-loop) if you have an idea how to ,where we need to use 2 levels of pivot ,somewhat related to this question

Comment: If `df`grouped by `ID`and values  in `LEVEL` column are null/nan, I do not want to add that column `LEVEL` to `columns`  parameter of `pivot_table`, how to do this?

Comment: @Scope You can filter them before pivoting by `df1 = df[df['LEVEL'].isna()]` and `df2 = df[df['LEVEL'].notna()]` and processing only df2.

Comment: Within an `ID` group if there are `na` `LEVEL`, I want to pivot and give one sheet name and if for all `ID` if there are are `na` `LEVEL` I want to pivot and give another sheet name. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Also after I create a `pivot` how do I sort values according to another `df`?Im able to do it before `pivot` and see `CATEG` in the order I want it to be, but after `pivot` orde gets changed, I cannot come to understand why