# Convert columns with large numbers and float64 as int type to suppress scientific formatting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

I tried many SO answers but nothing tried so far worked.I have a column in a `df`where there is a large value in a column like `89898989898989898` Whatever I do this is not being displayed as a number. All the cols are of float64 `dtype`.I do not have any float values in my `df`
After creating pivot I get a dataframe `df` and I tried converting to `int` then writing to excel, does not seem to have any difference and displays as scientific formatting(I can see the value when I click on the cell in the value bar) I could not convert to `int` directly as there are `Nan` values in the column :-

```
  ID CATEG   LEVEL     COLS    VALUE  COMMENTS
    1   A        2     Apple    1e+13 comment1
    1   A        3     Apple    1e+13 comment1
    1   C        1     Apple    1e+13 comment1
    1   C        2     Apple    345   comment1
    1   C        3     Apple    289   comment1
    1   B        1     Apple    712   comment1
    1   B        2     Apple    1e+13 comment1
    2   B        3     Apple    376   comment1
    2   C        None  Orange   1e+13 comment1
    2   B        None  Orange   135   comment1
    2   D        None  Orange   423   comment1
    2   A        None  Orange   866   comment1
    2            None  Orange   496   comment2
```

After pivot the `Apple` column looks like this (providing just sample values to show the scientific notation values) :-

```
   index    Apple
    1655    1e+13
    1656    1e+13
    1657    1e+13
    1658    NaN
    1659    NaN
    df=pd.pivot_table(dfe,index=['ID','CATEG','LEVEL'],columns=['COLS'],values=['VALUE'])
    df= df.fillna(0).astype(np.int64)
    with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx',options={'nan_inf_to_errors': True}) as writer :
            df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.dropna(how='all', axis=1).to_excel(writer,sheet_name=str(x.name),na_rep=0,index=True))
    writer.save()
```

What should I do to get rid of scientific formatting and get it displayed as a number in excel.
Also is there a way to autofit the columns in excel while writing from python to excel.Im using `pd.ExcelWriter` to write to excel

Comment: The problem is the category that excel assigns to the cells. If I put your example number into excel I also get scientific notation. But when I go to format cell --> Number and I pick number it changes it to a regular number.

Comment: No I don't think so as other columns from `df` are displayed as numbers correctly in excel

Answer (score 0):

You can use set_option to avoid scientific formating

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)
```

Also you can change column type with this command:

```
df['col'] = df[['col']].fillna(0)
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(int)
```

Comment: I cannot convert into `int` as I have `NaN` value as mentioned in my question, also tried to convert `NaN` to 0 then convert to `int`, I still get the error

Comment: You fill na with 0 and use astype int but still have error? can you check my second solution and let me know? if it doesnt work please upload part of your dataset so I can check

Comment: YEs I  have tried these before, I cannot try on one particular column as I have 78 columsn in total,so as I have posted in my question I have tried and yet issue was not resolved

Comment: `df= df.fillna(0).astype(np.int64)`

Answer (score 0):

The following code generates a Dataframe with two columns. One with text and one with numbers and writes them to excel and changes the format so in order for excel to display the numbers as dot separated integers rather than in scientific notation. If you prefer a different format I am sure you can adopt the format string in the code. I hope that's what you're looking for :).

```
col1 = [float("nan"),*np.random.randint(10**15,size=5)]
col2 = [random.choice(["apple", "orange"]) for _ in range (6)]

with pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_column_formats.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    pd.DataFrame(data={"numbers":col1, "strings":col2})\
        .to_excel(writer)
    
    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    format_ = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##'})
    worksheet.set_column('B:B', None, format_)
```

For your specific example try:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx',options={'nan_inf_to_errors': True}) as writer:
        df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.dropna(how='all', axis=1).to_excel(writer,sheet_name=str(x.name),na_rep=0,index=True))
    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    format_ = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##'})
    worksheet.set_column('C:C', None, format_)
    worksheet.set_column('E:E', None, format_)
```

Notice that I am guessing form [the other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64349629/how-to-drop-null-values-in-dataframe-after-groupby-while-writing-to-excel/64349685#64349685) that your columns with numbers will be C and E. You will probably have to widen the columns for the huge numbers. Excel will write ######### for it otherwise.

Comment: `data` will be my `dataframe`?

Comment: Data was data I have tried it on :D. But you can use `.style.format` on any `dataframe`. If you only want to `format` some columns you can do that by giving a key word argument `subset=a_list_of_columns_to_style`. Or you provide an example dataframe for me to work on.

Comment: I used `df=df.style.format(lambda x: "nan" if np.isnan(x) else int(x))` but did not work.(I had to use `groupby` next step). You can see for an example dataset and the code I use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64349629/how-to-drop-null-values-in-dataframe-after-groupby-while-writing-to-excel/64349685#64349685). You need to replace `VALUE`  column with float `dtype` and  `1e+13` notation value

Comment: Tried this `pd.DataFrame(data=df).style.format(lambda x: "nan" if np.isnan(x) else int(x))` , issue is not resolved

Comment: You have to do the `style.format` at then end right before you export to excel as it does not return a dataframe but a `styler object`

Comment: ok then could you show me where to add it here `with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx',options={'nan_inf_to_errors': True}) as writer :
        df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.dropna(how='all', axis=1).to_excel(writer,sheet_name=str(x.name),na_rep=0,index=True))
writer.save()`

Comment: I would guess right before the `to_excel` but I can't test it so I am not sure.

Comment: Hmm maybe try to provide a _minimal viable example_ to you question.

Comment: I have already provided a sample along with my question and also u can have a look at it  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64349629/how-to-drop-null-values-in-dataframe-after-groupby-while-writing-to-excel/64349685#64349685)

Comment: Sorry but you did not. A _minimal viable example_ means you give me something small that I can work on and you're happy when it worked with that. Maybe somebody else can help without more information.

Comment: I had provided more than enough information with rergards to scientific notation error, but as you requested for a "sample", provided that as well in the question, u can basically take any dataframe with scientific notation and try the code I have provided according to your column names to see or test if your code works

Comment: @Scope I changed my answer again. Now happy :D?

Comment: How do I make this work in my code (which i again already provided in question), I have `groupedby` and written to different sheets

Comment: `workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    format_ = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##'})
    worksheet.set_column('B:B', None, format_)`  If  I just need to add this block of code to make it work then in `writer.sheets`  I need to all all the sheets ..

Comment: @Scope Hahaha check it one more time.

Comment: By `worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']` all those formatting will be affected only to sheet 1 right

Comment: Exactly I am only setting sheet1 column C and E to the new formatting.

Comment: How do I set all the sheets I would create dynamically for the excel there. I cant use the code, as it shows `Sheet 1 ` error. How do I set for all shetts (or full workbook) and all columns (in all the sheets)